# What are the steps in creating app icon for ios?

Tags: unity

I have completed developing my game (iOS) and now preparing it to submit to the appstore. However, i have some confusion regarding app icon.

1>In Unity build->player settings, there are various sizes mentioned. Largest size is 180x180 px. But i read somewhere apple requires 512x512 px icon.

2>Is the build-->player settings the only place where i provide app icons or are there more steps involved in xcode? If there are, please provide link to some documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an official tutorial by Unity
http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=C3izqF6h_aY

Comment: Have seen that :) i want to know are those all steps or need anymore (regarding app icon that is)